# Docker not mounting a folder as volume

Tags: docker

I have a tomcat6 image which uses `/usr/local/tomcat` as catalina home. I am trying to mount a volume using this command:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v  /home/ubuntu/Springmvc:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps tomcat6.
```

When I browse to the container URL I can see tomcat running correctly (no error message) but there are no available applications.

I followed Docker's official volume documentation at http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes

I am using docker on ubuntu.

Springmvc is my project folder.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why did you add the boot2docker tag if you have an Ubuntu host?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem is you need to mount the directory inside the `webapps` folder, not over the top of it e.g: `-v /home/ubuntu/Springmvc:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/Springmvc`

Comment: it worked.But i have one doubt.When i  do changes in code its not reflecting.Any idea?

Comment: Yeah, you probably need to tell tomcat to reload. But that's a tomcat problem, not a docker problem.